# Как открыть elementor для редактирования файла?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Для удобства привожу скриншот wordpress-а с установленным плагином elementor

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом открыть elementor для редактирования файла?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=701pwm78Q90
с 19 минуты смотрите.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала необходимо зайти по пунктам меню **Страницы->Все страницы** .Затем необходимо навести курсор на нужную страницу и выбрать Редактировать в Elementor